# How to display BuddyPress avatar in bbPress?

Tags: wordpress, buddypress, bbpress

I have bbPress 2.1.2 and BuddyPress 1.6.1 installed on a 3.4.2 WordPress site.

I want to display BuddyPress avatars on the forums by bbPress.

How do I do that?

I've tried

```
include(WP_PLUGIN_DIR."/buddypress/bp-loader.php");
```

in `header.php`
and
called

```
bp_get_member_avatar()
```

but no success

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Let me know if this works for you.

```
echo bp_core_fetch_avatar( 'item_id='.get_post_author_id() );
```